# App Engine NDB Transaction Collision

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions

In the App Engine documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions), it says: **"If the transaction 'collides' with another, it fails; NDB automatically retries such failed transactions a few times."**

The meaning of this sentence is not totally clear to me. If transaction A begins first, and then transaction B begins in the middle of A's operation, does that mean that both A and B will fail and retry? Or does only B fail, and A continues?

Also, a related question: are there any cases in which a transaction would be partially completed and then rolled back? Or does each transaction attempt not enter the function at all until it has the opportunity to complete the function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely than not, one of the transaction would succeed and the other fail (and be re-tried), but you can't tell in advance which one; it **is** also possible that both might fail (and be separately re-tried).

And yes, `fail` DOES generally mean `partly progresses but then gets rolled back`.  It's an "optimistic concurrency" arrangement, not one based on pre-emptive `locking`.

Remember, potentially conflicting transactions are generally being requested on many distributed machines -- co-ordinating them by anything but "optimistic concurrency" (detect conflicts and roll back the ones that couldn't complete cleanly) would be unfeasible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! From what you wrote, it sounds like optimistic concurrency control does not guarantee that ANY of several concurrent requests will complete without interruption, as opposed to in a locking system (where requests will proceed sequentially, guaranteeing a baseline performance level). Given this I don't quite understand your last sentence; it seems that in a system with many concurrent requests a pessimistic control system would outperform an optimistic one. Would you mind pointing out the mistake in my reasoning? Thanks!

Comment: In a distributed system with many *clashing* near-simultaneous requests performance will be terrible anyway -- either due to the many retries or to the huge overhead of establishing distributed locks.  That's why e.g it's recommended to *shard* counters per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters .  But in a locking-based system you pay the same tremendously high price even when there is ZERO need for it -- transactions wouldn't clash -- in an optimistic one you only pay rarely, when needed.  Analogies: TCP exponential backoff; ethernet's triumph over token ring:-).